# List of objects, add properties together based of another property

Tags: c#, list, sum

I have a List that contains 2 properties per object. The properties are as follows:

```
string Project;
double Value;
```

So in any given case we might have a List of 5 objects, where 3 of them have a Project property called "Test" and the other 2 objects have a Project Property called "Others", but none of the 5 objects have the same "Value".

```
{
    Project = "Test" Value = 1, 
    Project = "Test" Value = 5, 
    Project = "Test" Value = 25,
    Project = "Others" Value = 89, 
    Project = "Others" Value = 151
}
```

Okay, I get a lot of data from a Database (I "Query" it out into a List of objects), then I take the specific properties I need from that List and add to my own List as follows.

```
public class Data
{
public string Project {get; set;}
public double Value {get; set;}
}
public List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();

foreach(var item in DatabaseList)
{
Data newData = new Data(
data.Project = item.Project;
data.Value = item.Project;
dataList.Add(newData);
}
```

This gives me my list of data that I somehow need to combine based on the property in "Project"

But I have a hard time figuring out how to seperate them from one another, my first thought was to find "Unique" "Projects" and adding that to a new List called "counter", to then loop through that list based of the "Project" property, so something like this:

```
List<Data> counter = dataList.GroupBy(x => x.Project).Select(First()).ToList();

foreach(var item in counter)
{
Data finalItem = new Data();
   foreach (var item2 in dataList)
   {
       if(item.Project == item2.Project)
       {
        finalItem.Project = item2.Project;
        finalItem.Value += item2.Value;
        finalList.Add(finalItem);
       }
   }
}
```

So I already know that the above is so messy its crazy, and its also not going to work, but this was the angle I was trying to take, I was also thinking whether I could maybe make use of Dictionary, but I feel like there is probably a super simple solution to something like this.

Comment: And what is your pboblem? What did you try and where **specifically** do you need help? Please provide your current code and in particular how you populate that list.

Comment: If you like to do that, then do it! You don't need our permission. It's quite straight forward. What have you tried?

Comment: Hey, sorry about the lack of details, I have updated it now, so you guys know a bit more.

Comment: Just a note: I think the originally expressed goal about calculating the `Value` sum for each project may have gotten lost in one of the edits that have been made to the question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your initial thoughts regarding making use of a dictionary are good. Your use of `.GroupBy()` is a first step to create that dictionary, where the project name is the dictionary `Key` and the sum of values for that project is the dictionary `Value`.

You already seem to be familiar with the *System.Linq* namespace. The extension method [`.ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0) exists in the same namespace, and can be used to define the `Key` and `Value` selector for each `KeyValuePair` (KVP) in the dictionary as follows:

```csharp
.ToDictionary(
    <selector for Key>,
    <selector for Value>
);
```

The dictionary may be created by utilizing `.ToDictionary()` directly after `.GroupBy()`, as follows:

```csharp
Dictionary<string, double> dataDictionary = dataList
    .GroupBy(item => item.Project)
    .ToDictionary(
        itemsByProject => itemsByProject.Key,
        itemsByProject => itemsByProject.Sum(item => item.Value));
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O6pRPT).

Comment: Thanks a lot Astrid, this did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to compute the total Value for objects with Project="Test" :

```
double TestsValue = my_list.Where(o=>o.Project=="Test").Sum(t=>t.Value);
```

and do the same for "Others".

Comment: Hey, sorry I should have been clearer, my bad. I do not know what the "Project" property is beforehand, these were just examples.

Comment: You can replace the hard coded string `"Test"` above with a string variable that is set at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're happy to return an IEnumerable of Data, you can do this:

```
var projects = dataList.GroupBy(p => p.Project)
                       .Select(grp => 
                           new Data 
                           { 
                               Project = grp.First().Project, 
                               Value = grp.Sum(pr => pr.Value) 
                           });
```